# Will the buffer be overwritten when async read?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I want to use boost::async_read after async_read_until. async_read_until can write to buffer some data after delimiter. Can i use safely boost async_read after async_read_until with the same buffer and dont lost data that already in buffer?

Comment: could you show code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

There are [dynamic buffers](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/DynamicBuffer.html) (streambuf, dynamic_string_buffer etc) that will retain the information.

If you use fixed buffer sequences, you can use [Buffer Arithmetic](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html#boost_asio.reference.buffer.buffer_arithmetic) to preserve a part of existing buffer.

> It might help to realize the flipside: `[async_]read_until` guarantees completion when the completion condition is met. However, it *may* have read more than that into the buffer. This is *why* [`consume(n)`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/DynamicBuffer_v1.html#:%7E:text=x.consume(n)) only consumes the prefix of a dynamic buffer.
>
> In fact when you issue another read[_until] using the same dynamic buffer might actually complete without another `asrs.async_read_some` on the underlying [AsyncReadStream](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html) if the existing buffer contents already match the completion condition.
>
> In extreme example, I recently started using this to demonstrate how read operations work on dynamic buffers without doing any true IO: e.g. [Unable to get all the data with boost asio read()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73329337/unable-to-get-all-the-data-with-boost-asio-read/73352461#73352461)

### Summarizing

Prefer a dynamic buffer that allows you to safely do what you describe.

Comment: Thanks. But I still have questions. I want to have 2 functions: async_read(sock, dest, bytes_count, error_code) that write to dest exactly bytes_count bytes; and async_read_line(sock, std::string s, error_code) that read from socket exactly one line. The problem is that boost::asio::async_read_until can read more than i want.

Comment: I decided that I need to write a wrapper over the socket, which inside itself can store the remainder of the call async_read_until, and then successfully use this buffer in subsequent calls of my function. But i need to erase elements from the beginning of my internal buffer after read/readline calls. So, std::vector, that can be used looks to slow. std::deque would be ideal, but i cant pass it to boost functions. Then i tried to use boost streambuf, but my object cant move now. Can you help, please?

Comment: Of course i can read byte by byte from socket, but will it be fast enough?

Comment: streambuf is the way. If you need it to be movable, use `unique_ptr<streambuf>`? "The problem is that boost::asio::async_read_until can read more than i want." - surely not. Your problem is that you consume more than you need: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d7cb1114c4323bb. The AsyncReadStream is the wrong abstraction to buffer in. Instead. buffer in the... buffer :)

Comment: Making it async - I would make the entire async session shared so you don't need movable buffers at all: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b512e4d51bf3e4c